# Table [tablename] is not locked

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a MySQL query that locks a table:

```
"LOCK TABLE table_1 WRITE"
```

After that i am executing some functions, and in one of those functions, I am executing another query, on another table that I haven't locked:

```
"SELECT * FROM completely_different_table_2"
```

Then i get the following error message as result:

```
Table 'completely_different_table_2' was not locked with LOCKED TABLES
```

Indeed, MySql is right to tell me that the table is not locked. But why does it throws an error? Anyone any ideas how I could solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to lock **every table**, that you want to use until the `LOCK` is released. You can give `completely_different_table_2` only a `READ LOCK`, which allows other processes to read this table while it is locked:

```
LOCK TABLES table_1 WRITE, completely_different_table_2 READ;
```

PS: MySQL has a reason to do so. If you request a `LOCK`, you want to freeze a consistent state of your data. If you read data from `completely_different_table_2` inside your `LOCK`, your data written to `table_1` will in some way depend on this other table. Therefore you don’t want anyone to change this table during your `LOCK` and request a `READ LOCK` for this second table as well. If your data written to `table_1` doesn’t depend on the other table, simply don’t query it until the `LOCK` is released.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, it works perfect. However, I am having a lot of tables, and a lot of people using them at the same time. Is there any workaround to lock just one table, while still using the others as normal?

Comment: Not really. And `LOCK`s can quickly lead to problems, when you have a lot of traffic on your db ([deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)). So ask, if you really need the `LOCK` and try to keep the `LOCK` as small and as short as possible.

Comment: Then i guess lock is not the best option to use here. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rinux If you are not intended to lock entire table but just some rows in it. then you can use INNODb as storage engine. It provides row level locking.

Comment: Thanks Uday, I am using innoDb. However, i need to lock the complete table.